# How to monitor passenger / mod_rails processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, passenger, mod-rails

I searched the site already but couldn't find any suitable information. As there is always some expert around I'm sure one of guys knows exactly what I'm searching for :-)

We're on a balanced system:

```
Machine 1:     HAProxy load balancer
Machine 2 & 3: Apache mod_rails and (of course) our Rails applications
```

Those were the days when we were able to monitor all Mongrel processes using monit (or other monitoring tools).

Is there any way to do an easy and clever monitoring of passenger processes with monit (or other tools), too? How can I dynamically get all pids of the running processes and pass them to monitoring?

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various options available. Here are some of them:

- The [passenger-status](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_inspecting_phusion_passenger_8217_s_internal_status) tool lets you inspect its internal status
- [FiveRuns Manage](http://blog.fiveruns.com/2008/7/30/another-look-phusion-passenger-and-fiveruns-manage) can monitor a Passenger installation
- [Scout](http://scoutapp.com/) can also monitor Passenger

Comment: Oh, and FiveRuns Manage has been discontinued - http://blog.fiveruns.com/2009/8/12/end-of-life-for-manage

Answer (score 3):

I made a plugin which make Passenger processes monitorable by Monit:
https://github.com/romanbsd/passenger_monit

Answer (score 1):

Its a little ghetto but run these commands
watch passenger-status
watch passenger-memory-stats

then install and run htop

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and I think I found the thing your looking for. He uses a script which runs off "passenger-status" as John Topley said. 
http://blog.slowb.ro/2013/06/18/add-passenger-status-to-monitoring-on-zenoss/